# Why do I get a stack smashing error using MPI_Bcast and -O3 compiler flag, but everything works without -O3?

Tags: c, mpi

I am pretty new to MPI, so apologies if this is simple.

I have some code from a month or two ago that has been working fine, but I decided to go back and revise it.  (It was written when I was just starting out, and it's not a performance critical section.)  The code basically generates a random graph on one process and then shares the results with all other processes. An excerpt from the baby's-first-steps version follows:

```
unsigned int *graph;

if (commrank == 0) {
    graph = gengraph(params); //allocates graph memory in function
    if (commsize > 1) {
        for (int k=1; k<commsize; k++) 
            MPI_Send(graph, n*n, MPI_UNSIGNED, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
} else {
    MPI_Status recvStatus;
    graph = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*n*n);
    MPI_Recv(graph, n*n, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recvStatus);
}
```

While obviously naive, this worked just fine for a while, before I chose to go back and do it in what I thought was the proper fashion:

```
if (commrank == 0) {
    graph = gengraph(params);
    MPI_Bcast(graph, n*n, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else {
    graph = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*n*n);
    MPI_Bcast(graph, n*n, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

The problem is, I keep getting when "stack smashing" errors in the second version when I compile with -O3 optimization, though it works fine when compiled unoptimized.  Note that I have checked the graph allocation function multiple times and debugged it, and it appears to be fine. I have also debugged the second version, and it appears to work fine.  The crash occurs later when I try to free the graph memory.  (Note that this is not a double free error, and, again, it works fine in the naive implementation and has for some time.)

One final wrinkle: The **first** version also fails if, instead of using the `recvStatus` variable, I instead use `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`. And, again, this only fails with -O3.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  If it's any help, I'm using mpicc on top of gcc 7.5.0, but I imagine I'm doing something stupid rather than encountering a compiler problem.

Comment: have you ran your app under `valgrind`? the crash could be the consequence of some previous memory corruption.

Comment: The issue is likely in the code that follows the one shown here. Try Clang with Address Sanitizer. It may help you pinpoint the source of the issue. Weird things happening at higher compiler optimisation levels is not unheard of.

Comment: Thanks @gilles-gouaillardet.  I have run valgrind on the code in the past, though I have found it a bit tricky with MPI programs.  I will sort through valgrind's results with more care.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @hristo-iliev.  I will look into Clang with Address Sanitizer.  I have never used it.  As you suggest, the problem, while definitely associated with the excerpted code segment, does seem to actually bite me later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the mpicc compiler to Clang and used Address Sanitizer, per the suggestion of @hristo-iliev, and found an error in a subsequent MPI call (a recv with the wrong count size).  This led to the undefined behavior.  Notably, the address sanitizer pinpointed location of the error quite clearly, while valgrind only gave rather opaque indications that something was going on in MPI (as, well, it always does).

Apologies to the StackOverflow community for this, as the code above was not the culprit (not entirely surprising).  It was just some standard undefined behavior due to sloppiness.